# Solving $\ddot y = \dot y\cdot y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form:

$c_1\ddot y=c_2y\cdot\dot y$

Cant seem to think of any function that has that property so I am not being able to solve it. Is there a general way to solve any differential equation of second order instead of guessing functions?

Comment: @Arthur im very new to solving 2nd order DEs so can you tell me how exactly should i try to do that? Also is there a general way to solve any 2nd order DE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''=cyy'$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}y'=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\frac{c}{2}y^{2}\Big)$$
Thus
$$y'=\frac{c}{2}y^{2}+k$$
$$x+k_{2}=\int\frac{dy}{\frac{c}{2}y^{2}+k_{1}}$$
I hope you can continue

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate once and get

$$\dot y=ay^2+b.$$

Then

$$\frac{dy}{ay^2+b}=dt.$$

Depending on the signs, the antiderivative will be an $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$.

Comment: Im not getting how did u arrive at the second step?

Comment: OHHH got it nevermind. Im v dumb